# how to optimize this sql when use order by select

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

```
select id, col1,col2,col3,seq 
from `table` 
order by seq asc
```

i have already created index on 'seq', but i found that it doesn't use the index and use filesort when selecting , because the col1 may save some large data ,so i don't want to create the covering index in this table, so it is have some solutions to optimize this sql or table or index, thanks ,my English is not good

Comment: Show your CREATE TABLE

Comment: With no filtering criteria an index that's not covering is, afaik, pretty useless

Comment: I think you'd be more likely to see the index used if you had a limit.  without, an index may save sorting but make reading all the data take longer.  does `... from table force index (nameofyourseqindex) order by...`  make any difference?

Comment: If you are selecting all the rows of the table, using the index can be counter-productive. The engine is right to ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL query optimizer apparently estimated the cost of using the index and concluded that it would be better to just do a table-scan and use a filesort of the result.

There is overhead to using a non-covering index. It reads the index in sorted order, but then has to dereference the primary key to get the other columns not covered by the row.

By analogy, this is like reading a book by looking up every word in alphabetical order in the index at the back, and then flipping back to the respect pages of the book, one word at a time. Time-consuming, but it's one way of reading the book in order by keyword.

That said, a filesort has overhead too. The query engine has to collect matching rows, and sort them manually, potentially using temporary files. This is expensive if the number of rows is large. You haven't described the size of your table in number of rows.

If the table you are testing has a small number of rows, the optimizer might have reasoned that it would be quick enough to do the filesort, so it would be unnecessary to read the rows by the index.

Testing with a larger table might give you different results from the optimizer.

The query optimizer makes the right choice in the majority of cases. But it's not infallible. If you think forcing it to use the index is better in this case, you can use the [FORCE INDEX hint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html) to make it believe that a table-scan is prohibitively expensive. Then if the index is usable at all, it'll prefer the index.

```
select id, col1,col2,col3,seq 
from `table` FORCE INDEX(seq)
order by seq asc
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer, it helped me ：）